# WHERE clause on a field that was calculated with a CASE --SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

In this query I'm writing for an SSRS rpt, I am changing NULL to read 'Unclassified' using a CASE And then I want to filter by the multi-select parameter (@Channel) that will include "Unclassified".

```
SELECT Top (Convert(int,@CustNum)) 
       A
      ,B
      ,C
      ,CASE WHEN CH.Channel IS NULL THEN 'Unclassified'
            ELSE CH.Channel END AS Channel
FROM MYtable MT
LEFT JOIN ChannelTable CH
    ON MT.ChannelKey = CH.ChannelKey
WHERE Channel IN (@Channel)
```

I can't just use a subquery because the user defines the number of records that they want to see via the @Custnum param.

EDIT:  Thanks for all the great answers, I learned a few things.

Comment: You could also use isnull(CH.Channel. 'Unclassified') as Channel

Comment: And if you're hoping to have several values in @Channel, like 'X','Y','Z', that will not work unless you construct dynamic SQL for the in clause

Comment: Thanks for the isnull tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT Top (Convert(int,@CustNum)) A, B, C, Channel
FROM (SELECT A
            ,B
            ,C
            ,CASE WHEN CH.Channel IS NULL THEN 'Unclassified'
                  ELSE CH.Channel END AS Channel
      FROM MYtable MT
      LEFT JOIN ChannelTable CH
          ON MT.ChannelKey = CH.ChannelKey
) AS T
WHERE Channel IN (@Channel);
```

Or this:

```
SELECT Top (Convert(int,@CustNum)) 
       A
      ,B
      ,C
      ,CASE WHEN CH.Channel IS NULL THEN 'Unclassified'
            ELSE CH.Channel END AS Channel
FROM MYtable MT
LEFT JOIN ChannelTable CH
    ON MT.ChannelKey = CH.ChannelKey
WHERE CASE WHEN CH.Channel IS NULL THEN 'Unclassified'
           ELSE CH.Channel END IN (@Channel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` to select the calculated field. Then use its alias in place of `Channel`:

```
SELECT Top (Convert(int,@CustNum))
    A
    ,B
    ,C
    ,x.Channel
    FROM MYtable MT
    LEFT JOIN ChannelTable CH ON MT.ChannelKey = CH.ChannelKey
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE 
                           WHEN CH.Channel IS NULL THEN 'Unclassified'
                           ELSE CH.Channel 
                 END) x(Channel)
    WHERE x.Channel IN (@Channel)
```

Comment: This looks great.  I'm not familiar with Cross Apply, will dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Repeat the same CASE in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

This might be enough:

```
SELECT Top (Convert(int,@CustNum)) 
       A
      ,B
      ,C
      ,COALESCE(CH.Channel,'Unclassified') AS Channel
FROM MYtable MT
LEFT JOIN ChannelTable CH
    ON MT.ChannelKey = CH.ChannelKey
WHERE COALESCE(Channel,'Unclassified') IN (@Channel)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a subquery:

```
select Top (Convert(int,@CustNum)) * from(
              SELECT 
              A
             ,B
             ,C
             ,CASE WHEN CH.Channel IS NULL THEN 'Unclassified'
                   ELSE CH.Channel END AS Channel
              FROM MYtable MT
              LEFT JOIN ChannelTable CH ON MT.ChannelKey = CH.ChannelKey)t
WHERE Channel IN (@Channel)
```

Comment: That's what I did first.  It doesn't work because if you want top 25 records, then you filter out the ones that aren't in Channel, you have fewer than 25 records.

Comment: The table that I'm selecting from is really large and I could be wrong here, but it seemed to me that it would be really inefficient to select all of the data and then select the top 25 from that.